# Zip4j Excluding Folders from Zip

Tags: java, zip, directory, php-ziparchive, zip4j

I have a directory with some folders that should be skipped and not added to the target `ZIP` file. I marked them as hidden on `Windows` and I can query this attribute using Java code as follows:

```
new File("C:\\myHiddenFolder").isHidden();
```

However, I don't know how to use this with the following [`Zip4j`](http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/)-based method to skip adding those respective directories:

```
public File createZipArchive(String sourceFilePath) throws ZipException, IOException
{
    ZipParameters zipParameters = new ZipParameters();
    zipParameters.setCompressionMethod(Zip4jConstants.COMP_DEFLATE);
    zipParameters.setCompressionLevel(Zip4jConstants.DEFLATE_LEVEL_ULTRA);
    zipParameters.setEncryptFiles(true);
    zipParameters.setEncryptionMethod(Zip4jConstants.ENC_METHOD_AES);
    zipParameters.setAesKeyStrength(Zip4jConstants.AES_STRENGTH_256);
    zipParameters.setPassword("MyPassword");

    String baseFileName = FileNameUtilities.getBaseFileName(sourceFilePath);
    String destinationZipFilePath = baseFileName + "." + EXTENSION;

    ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(destinationZipFilePath);
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFilePath);

    // Recursively add directories
    if (sourceFile.isDirectory())
    {
        File[] childrenFiles = sourceFile.listFiles();

        if (childrenFiles != null)
        {
            for (File folder : childrenFiles)
            {
                if (folder.isHidden()) // Nope, no recursive checking!
                {
                    // This is the problem, it adds the parent folder and all child folders without allowing me to check whether to exclude any of them...
                    zipFile.addFolder(folder.getAbsolutePath(), zipParameters);
                }
            }
        }
    } else
    {
        // Add just the file
        zipFile.addFile(new File(sourceFilePath), zipParameters);
    }

    return zipFile.getFile();
}
```

Note that this method only works when the (hidden) folders are in the most upper level but it should work for any depth.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To solve this I went with moving all hidden folders out, package the zip file and move the folders back:

```
HiddenDirectoriesMover hiddenDirectoriesMover = new HiddenDirectoriesMover(sourceFilePath);
        hiddenDirectoriesMover.removeFiles();

// Create zip

hiddenDirectoriesMover.returnFiles();
```

A dirty work-around but does the job since `zipParameters.setReadHiddenFiles(false);` [is not working as expected](http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/forum/index.php?topic=395.0):

```
public static ArrayList getFilesInDirectoryRec(File path, 
        boolean readHiddenFiles) throws ZipException {

    if (path == null) {
        throw new ZipException("input path is null, cannot read files in the directory");
    }

    ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
    File[] filesAndDirs = path.listFiles();
    List filesDirs = Arrays.asList(filesAndDirs);

    if (!path.canRead()) {
        return result; 
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < filesDirs.size(); i++) {
        File file = (File)filesDirs.get(i);
        if (file.isHidden() && !readHiddenFiles) {
            // The first hidden file causes a return and skipping everything else (!)
            return result;
        }
        result.add(file);
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            List deeperList = getFilesInDirectoryRec(file, readHiddenFiles);
            result.addAll(deeperList);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `net.lingala.zip4j.model.ExcludeFileFilter`.

```java
try (ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(destinationFilePath)) {
  ZipParameters parameters = new ZipParameters();
  ExcludeFileFilter excludeFileFilter = file -> file.isDirectory() && 
isIllegalDirectoy(file);
  if (sourceFile.isDirectory) {
    zipFile.addFolder(sourceFile, parameters);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add `zipParameters.setReadHiddenFiles(false);`, zip4j will not add hidden folders and files to `ZipFile`.

Comment: That is wrong because it will stop when the first hidden folder has been found. I read the implementation as well and that's what it does.